# Overflow Toolbar Icon (Three dots) doens't change color (API 15)

Tags: android, colors, icons, android-toolbar

I want to tint the icon white.

This is the toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/PopupToolbar"/>
```

And the styles:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="carbon_Theme.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/texto</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The thing is, all attributes works excepts the #%&@! "three dots" color. In a `API 23` device the icon is white. The problem only happens on a `API 15` devices, where it's black. WHY.

P.S. I also tried to apply themes directly:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

But still happens. `API 23` white icon, `API 15` black icon.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? It also happens to me for API 17. It started happening when I upgrade to support library 23.2.0

Comment: @AitorViana Nope. I tried a lot of solutions, nothing worked. I'm using 23.2.0 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be running into an issue with drawables being auto-generated by Gradle. We had a similar issue but with the Up Navigation Arrow in a navigation tool bar.

For Gradle 2.0:

```
 // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
  }  
}
```

For Gradle 1.5

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
}
```

The full article is here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Even if you're not specifically using the new Vector Drawables out of the Support Library, this still affected our project.

Comment: I didn't read all the "Support Vector" stuff when I upgraded, my bad. And you were right, it was this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.  What worked for me was setting the theme in the layout file using:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    :
    android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme" />
```

and in styles.xml

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    :
</style>
```